# Understanding `this` behaviour where `arguments` are involved

Tags: javascript, arguments, this

So, I have 3 functions as follows:

```
function a() {
  arguments[0]();
}

function b(fn) {
  fn();
}

function c() {
  console.log(this);
}
```

Now, consider the outputs:

```
a(c) // Arguments
b(c) // Window
a(() => {console.log(this}) // Window
b(() => {console.log(this)}) // Window
```

Why does `a(c)` output Arguments while it is window (considering non-strict) in all other cases?

Comment: The only seemingly odd case here is the first. With `foo.bar()`, `foo` will be this. This is equivalent for `foo["bar"]()`, therefore, it is also equivalent to `arguments[0]()`.

Comment: Because `arguments[0]();` is a method call.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi . It took me a while to get my head around this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript `this` usually refers to the object from which the function was called (unless it's an arrow function). So for example if we do something like this:

```js
var obj = { fun: function() { console.log(this); } }
var obj1 = { fun: obj.fun, otherProperty: 123 }
obj.fun(); // equivalent to obj["fun"]()
obj1.fun(); // equivalent to obj1["fun"]()
```

We will find out that in the first call `this` refers to `obj` and in the second it refers to `obj1` even though it's the same function.

Now, the `arguments` variable is an object which stores all the arguments which were passed to the function. If an argument was a function and you access it through the `arguments` object, it becomes a "parent" object from which the function was called and it becomes the new `this` in the function's execution context. You can consider your case to be equal to something like this:

```js
function c() {
  console.log(this);
}
var arguments = { "0" : c }
arguments["0"]() // will log the arguments object
```

In your second invocation (`b(c)`) the function passed as an argument is called directly inside the parent function, without accessing it through a proxy object - in that case `this` will be copied from the parent execution scope, which is `window`.

In the third and fourth example both functions are defined using the arrow function, which saves the value of `this` from the context in which they were created and they prevent this value from being changed.

More about arrow functions: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)